# Handling large datasets in charts quickely

Tags: c#

I have a large dataset(around 50000 points) which has be visualized in a line chart.The size of Canvas may vary according to the size of dataset. Massive amount of points makes the drawing too slow.It also results in cluttering and overlapping of points due to plotting of several points close to each other.So visual representation of data will be unsatisfactory. How can I display subset of available points which will increase the performance? Can anybody suggest me with a suitable algorithm which will help to extract the subset of actual number of points?

Answer (score 0):

everything i can think of would be a compromise...:

to keep it simple let's say you have a List with 50k entries to vizualize,
but you only want to draw 1k pts for performance reasons...

some different approaches would be...:

take every n'th pt so you get 1k vals:

```
List<double> src = ... //50k entries
List<double> viz = new List<double>();
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    viz.Add(src[(int)(i * (src.Length / 1000d))];
```

another approach would get the avg. to the pts...:

```
List<double> src = ... //50k entries
List<double> viz = new List<double>();
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    int from = (int)(i * (src.Length / 1000d));
    int to = (int)((i+1) * (src.Length / 1000d));
    double avg = 0;
    for(int j=from;j<to;j++)
        avg += src[j];
    viz.Add(avg/(to-from));
}
```

code untested - just some thoughts...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Taking average of adjacent points would reduce the size to half.But my question is, if suppose the two points are (1,5) (80,90) then average will be 47 which will not depict the appropriate value.Taking average will be helpful only when the points are close to each other.Is ther any other way in which I can reduce the number?

Comment: According to me we can reduce the size of collection by excluding points which will not affect shape of the chart much.For example if suppose there are points like (1,2)(2,4)(3,6) which passes through same line.Then the point (2,4) can be eliminated.Will this be a good solution or is there any other way in which I can extract the subset.